# React Native POST Method Issues

Tags: json, react-native, post, fetch-api

I have read many questions similar to mine but none solved my issue,
my fetch (Get Method) is working fine but the (POST METHOD) shows **Unexpected end of JSON input**

```
  fetch('http://monasabat-app.com/Queries/sub_cat.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          id: 3

        }),
      }).then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({
                fsubCategory: responseJson.sub_cat
            })
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });

}
```

And this is the response I got by POSTMAN

```
{
"sub_cat": [
    {
        "id": "4",
        "sub_cat": "sbu1",
        "img_path": "url"
    },
    {
        "id": "9",
        "sub_cat": "sub2",
        "img_path": "url"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you try in postMan using `Content-Type: application/json` you will notice you don't get any response.

```
POST /Queries/sub_cat.php HTTP/1.1
Host: monasabat-app.com
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: c60774f8-1aaa-4cf8-8aa3-abcab34b05e3

{id:3}
```

The `unexpected end of JSON input` it's because it's trying to parse an empty string.
So it's not an issue related to fetch, just try the following to get the proper response:

```
fetch('http://monasabat-app.com/Queries/sub_cat.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: 'id=3',
})
```

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 4